# "Doesn't have" filter for from field not applying

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I am using filters to better organize my emails. What I am trying to do , I believe, is relatively straight forward but I am not getting the result I'm looking for.

I get emails from `"somename@somedomain.com"` and emails from lots of other sources using the same domain. What I was to do is send any emails that are from `"somename@somedomain.com"` to get one label and emails from any other address with the same domain and NOT `"somename"` will get another label.

So I went into my filters, I created a filter that has `"somename@somedomain.com"` in the "From" field. That gets label A.

I created another filter that has `"@somedomain.com"` as the from section and `"from:somename@somedomain.com"` in the "doesn't have" field. These are to have label B applied to them.

I'm getting emails from `"somename@somedomain.com"` labeled both A and B. I've also tried putting `"somedomain.com -somename@somedomain.com"` in the second filters from field and have got the same result.

Could someone tell me what I may be doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2):

Just got this to work by creating both filters in the `From` field. The following are the searches applied (note: I'm not sure whether or not you were using quotation marks in your filters before, but I did not)

1. Label A (for the specific email address at the domain) `from:(name@domain.com)`
2. Label B (all emails from the domain *other than* the specific email address) `from:(domain.com -name)`